# Laravel route returns a 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm staring blind at a supposingly easy issue. I have defined the following routes in my web.php file.

```
Route::resource('objects', 'ObjectController');
Route::get('objects/grid','ObjectController@grid')->name('objects.grid');
```

This results in the following list of routes:

```
MACBOOKPRO:laravel-test user$ php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | objects                | objects.index    | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@index                            | web         |
|        | POST      | objects                | objects.store    | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@store                            | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | objects/create         | objects.create   | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@create                           | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | objects/grid           | objects.grid     | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@grid                             | web         |
|        | DELETE    | objects/{object}       | objects.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@destroy                          | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | objects/{object}       | objects.show     | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@show                             | web         |
|        | PUT|PATCH | objects/{object}       | objects.update   | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@update                           | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | objects/{object}/edit  | objects.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@edit                             | web         |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Going to http://localhost:8000/objects/grid does always return a 404 page. So there must be a conflict with other routes. If I change the 'objects/grid' to 'object/grid' and then it works.

A second pair of eyes is welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the ordering of your route file:

```
Route::get('objects/grid','ObjectController@grid')->name('objects.grid');
Route::resource('objects', 'ObjectController');
```

Route resources should be put at the bottom of your route list. This is because there is no difference between the GET objects/{object} and GET objects/grid or even objects/create. If it goes to look up the route objects/grid and objects/{object} is higher on the list, it will assume grid is an {object} and go to that route.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Would never have thought of that.